# Parsing Arguments to Function

Tags: python

I was trying to monitor source servers for crashes and restart automatically using RCON. Found a python script but unable to add argument parameter "-x" for port since the source code has no options to enter port. Tried myself but new to python. It's default set to 27015.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#SRCDS.py
#Half-Life 2 and Half-Life Dedicated Server Interface for Python
#Released under the LGPL (http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html)
#
#Christopher Munn
#Based off (most code copied from) SRCDS.py by Sean C. Steeg
#

__author__ = 'Christopher Munn'
__license__ = 'http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html'
__date__ = '07 Mar 2006'
__version__ = '2.02'
__credits__ = """Sean C. Steeg for SRCDS.py 1.01.
                 Bryan Gerber, for the original HLDS.py.
                 The players and staff of TacticalGamer.com, who make us want to do stuff like this.
              """

import socket, re, xdrlib, string, sys, os
from optparse import OptionParser

#Server Query Constants
DETAILS = "TSource Engine Query\x00"
DETAILS_RESP_HL2 = 'I'
DETAILS_RESP_HL1 = 'm'
GETCHALLENGE = 'W'
CHALLENGE = 'A'
PLAYERS = 'U'
PLAYERS_RESP = 'D'
RULES = 'V'
RULES_RESP = 'E'
#HL2 RCON Constants
SERVERDATA_RESPONSE_VALUE = 0
SERVERDATA_AUTH_RESPONSE = 2
SERVERDATA_EXECCOMMAND = 2
SERVERDATA_AUTH = 3
RCON_EMPTY_RESP = (10,0,0,'','')
#HL1 RCON Constants
RCON_CHALLENGE = "challenge rcon\n"

##################################################
# Network data manipulation
def hldsunpack_int(data):
    """
Network traffic is big endian, and xdrlib wants little endian, meaning the
bytes need to be reversed in order for xdrlib to work its magic."""
    s = ""
    for c in data:
        s = c + s
    p = xdrlib.Unpacker(s)
    return p.unpack_int()

def hldsunpack_float(data):
    """
Network traffic is big endian, and xdrlib wants little endian, meaning the
bytes need to be reversed in order for xdrlib to work its magic."""
    s = ""
    for c in data:
        s = c + s
    p = xdrlib.Unpacker(s)
    return p.unpack_float()

def hldspack_int(integer):
    s = ""
    p = xdrlib.Packer()
    p.pack_int(integer)
    data = p.get_buffer()
    for c in data:
        s = c + s
    return s

##################################################
# Functions for reading packets 
def read_byte(data):
    return (ord(data[0]), data[1:])

def read_char(data):
    return (str(data[0]), data[1:])

def read_string(data):
    s = ''
    i = 0
    while 1:
        if str(data[i]) != '\x00':
            s = s + str(data[i])
            i += 1
        else:
            break
    return (s, data[i+1:])

def read_int(data):
    ret = hldsunpack_int(data[0:4])
    return (ret, data[4:])

def read_float(data):
    ret = hldsunpack_float(data[0:4])
    return (ret, data[4:])

##################################################
# Exceptions
class SRCDS_Error(Exception):
    """Base error."""
    pass

class RCON_Error(Exception):
    """Raised when a command requiring RCON is given, but the RCON password is missing or incorrect."""
    pass

##################################################
# SRCDS class
class SRCDS:
    """
HL2DS/HLDS Interface class. Supports HL2 and HL servers.

Initialization: OBJ = SRCDS(host, [port=27015], [rconpass=''], [timeout=2.0])
Note: timeout is in seconds. host may be ip or hostname
    """

    def __init__(self, host, port=27015, rconpass='', timeout=10.0):
        self.ip, self.port, self.rconpass, self.timeout = socket.gethostbyname(host), port, rconpass, timeout
        self.udpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.tcpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.udpsock.settimeout(self.timeout)
        self.tcpsock.settimeout(self.timeout)
        self.udpsock.connect((self.ip, self.port))
        self.challenge, self.rcon_challenege, self.req_id, self.hl = -1, 0, 0, 0
        if self.rconpass: 
            self._authenticate_rcon()

    ##################################################
    # RCON Packet functions
    def send_packet(self, command, string1, string2=''):
        """Crafts and sends a packet to the server."""
        #Increment self.req_id, so all commands have unique id
        self.req_id += 1
        #Make the packet from the end going backwards
        packet = string1 + '\x00' + string2 + '\x00'
        #Add command
        packet = hldspack_int(command) + packet
        #Add request_id
        packet = hldspack_int(self.req_id) + packet
        #Add an int of the packet length
        packet = hldspack_int(len(packet)) + packet
        #Send packet to server
        self.tcpsock.send(packet)
        #Return req_id of packet
        return self.req_id

    def read_packet(self):
        """Parses a single response packet from the server."""
        raw_packetlen = self.tcpsock.recv(4)
        packetlen = hldsunpack_int(raw_packetlen)
        raw_packet = self.tcpsock.recv(packetlen)
        req_id = hldsunpack_int(raw_packet[0:4])
        command = hldsunpack_int(raw_packet[4:8])
        raw_packet = str(raw_packet[8:])
        if len(raw_packet) == 2:
            strs = ['', '']
        else:
            strs = re.split('[\000]', raw_packet[:-1], 1)
        return (packetlen, req_id, command, strs[0], strs[1])    

    def _authenticate_rcon(self):
        if not self.rconpass: raise RCON_Error, 'Empty RCON password.'
        if self.hl == 0:
            self.details()
        if self.hl == 1:
            self._authenticate_rcon_hl1()
        else:
            self._authenticate_rcon_hl2()

    def _authenticate_rcon_hl1(self):
        self.rcon_challenge =  self._any_response(RCON_CHALLENGE)[15:-2]
        response = self._any_rcon_response_hl1('say')
        if response == 'Bad rcon_password.':
            raise RCON_Error, 'Invalid RCON password.'

    def _authenticate_rcon_hl2(self):
        self.tcpsock.connect((self.ip, self.port))
        req_id = self.send_packet(SERVERDATA_AUTH, self.rconpass, '')
        i = 0
        result = RCON_EMPTY_RESP
        while result != (10,req_id,SERVERDATA_AUTH_RESPONSE,'',''):
            result = self.read_packet()
            if result[1] == -1:
                raise RCON_Error, 'Invalid RCON password.'

    def _any_rcon_response(self, command):
        """
This function returns the raw response for commands requiring RCON.
No parsing is done by this function.
        """
        if self.hl == 1:
            return self._any_rcon_response_hl1(command)
        else:
            return self._any_rcon_response_hl2(command)[3]

    def _any_rcon_response_hl1(self, command):
        query = "rcon " + self.rcon_challenge + ' "' + self.rconpass + '" ' + command
        return self._any_response(query)[1:]

    def _any_rcon_response_hl2(self, command):
        req_id = self.send_packet(SERVERDATA_EXECCOMMAND, command)
        result = RCON_EMPTY_RESP
        while result[1] != req_id:
            result = self.read_packet()
        return result                

    ##################################################
    # RCON functions
    def set_rconpass(self, password):
        '''
        sets the rcon password after-the-fact, in case you did not specify 
        this in the constructor.
        '''
        self.rconpass = password
        self._authenticate_rcon()

    def rcon_command(self, command):
        '''
        executes any rcon command on the server.
        '''
        return self._any_rcon_response(command)

    def changelevel(self, map):
        '''
        changes the map.
        '''
        self._any_rcon_response('changelevel %s' %map)

    def ban(self,steamid,length=0):
        """
        Bans a user with a given steamid; length given in minutes
        """
        self.rcon_command("banid %d %s" % (length,steamid)) 
        self.rcon_command("writeid") 


    def unban(self,steamid):
        """
        Unbans a user with a given steamid.
        """
        self.rcon_command("removeid %s" % steamid) 
        self.rcon_command("writeid") 

    def say(self, statement):
        '''
        cause the console to say something in-game to the players.
        '''
        self._any_rcon_response('say %s' %statement)

    def quit(self):
        '''
        quits the server.
        '''
        self._any_rcon_response('quit')

    def restart(self):
        '''
        restarts the server.
        '''
        self._any_rcon_response('_restart')

    def version(self):
        '''
        returns the version information for the host srcds server.
        '''
        d = self.status()
        return d['version']

    def currentmap(self):
        '''
        returns the current map that the server is running.
        '''
        d = self.status()
        return d['map']

    def nplayers(self):
        '''
        returns the number of players present on the server.
        '''
        d = self.status()
        return d['players']

    def cvar(self, var):
        '''
        returns the value of any public console variable.
        '''
        raw_status = self._any_rcon_response(var)
        val = re.match('^"(.*?)" = "(.*?)"', raw_status)
        if val:
            return val.group(2)
        else:
            return None


    def status(self):
        '''
        returns two dictionaries: info, and player.
        the info dictionary contains: map, version, players, slots, name, ip, port, fps, cpu_usage, in, out, users
        player is a dictionary of dictionaries, keyed by the user id.  Each dictionary is the status info on a player.
        '''
        raw_status = self._any_rcon_response('status')
        raw_stats = self._any_rcon_response('stats')
        info = {} 
        lines = re.split("\n",raw_status)
        line = lines.pop(0)
        while (line == '' or line[0] != '#') and len(lines) != 0:
            parts = line.split(":")
            kw = parts[0].strip()
            if kw == "version":
                info['version'] = parts[1].strip()
            elif kw == "map":
                info['map'] = parts[1].split()[0]
            elif kw == "udp/ip":
                info['ip'] = parts[1].strip()
                info['port'] = parts[2].strip()
            elif kw == "hostname":
                info['name'] = parts[1].strip()
            elif kw == "players":
                #players :  17 (24 max)
                t = parts[1].split('(')
                info['players']   = int(t[0])
                info['slots'] = int(t[1].split()[0])
            line = lines.pop(0)
        keys = re.split(' +', line)
        keys.pop(0)
        if self.hl == 1:
            temp = keys[0]
            keys[0] = keys[1]
            keys[1] = temp
        players = {}
        for line in lines:
            if line and line[0] == '#':
                line = re.split('"', line, 3)
                id = int(re.split(' +', line[0])[1])
                players[id] = {}
                players[id] [keys[1]] = line[1]
                values = re.split(" +", line[2])
                if self.hl == 1:
                    values.pop(0)
                for i, key in enumerate(keys[2:]):
                   players[id][key] = values[i+1]

        # now that we are finishing parsing through the status output, parse through
        # the stats output.
        lines = raw_stats.split('\n')
        items = lines[1].split() 
        info['cpu_usage'] = items[0]
        info['in']        = items[1]
        info['out']       = items[2]
        info['uptime']    = items[3]
        info['users']     = items[4]
        info['fps']       = items[5]

        # finally, add whatever is in the details dictionary to our info dictionary.
        d = self.details()
        for k,v in d.iteritems(): info[k] = v

        return (info,players)

    ##################################################
    # Query packet functions
    def _any_response(self, query):
        """
This assembles mult-packet responses and returns the raw response (sans the four \xFF's).  No parsing is done by this function.
        """
        self.udpsock.send('\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF' + query)
        data = self.udpsock.recv(4096)
        if data[0] == '\xFE':
            num_packets = ord(data[8]) & 15
            packets = [' ' for i in range(num_packets)]
            for i in range(num_packets):
                if i != 0:
                    data = self.udpsock.recv(4096)
                index = ord(data[8]) >> 4
                packets[index] = data[9:]
            data = ''
            for i, packet in enumerate(packets):
                data = data + packet
        return data[4:]

    ##################################################
    # Queries
    def getchallenge(self):
        raw_challenge = self._any_response(GETCHALLENGE)
        if raw_challenge[0] != CHALLENGE: 
            raise SRCDS_Error, 'GetChallenge Query Error: Unknown response type'
        data = raw_challenge[1:]
        self.challenge, data = read_int(data)
        return self.challenge

    def details(self):
        raw_details = self._any_response(DETAILS)
        if raw_details[0] == DETAILS_RESP_HL2:
            self.hl = 2
            return self._details_hl2(raw_details[1:])
        elif raw_details[0] == DETAILS_RESP_HL1:
            self.hl = 1
            return self._details_hl1(raw_details[1:])
        else:
            raise SRCDS_Error, 'Detail Query Error: Unknown response type'


    def _details_hl2(self, data):
        detaildict = {}
        detaildict['hl_version'] = 2
        detaildict['protocol_version'], data = read_byte(data)
        detaildict['server_name'], data = read_string(data)
        detaildict['current_map'], data = read_string(data)
        detaildict['game_directory'], data = read_string(data)
        detaildict['game_description'], data = read_string(data)
        aid1, data = read_byte(data)
        aid2, data = read_byte(data)
        detaildict['app_id'] = (aid1 * 0x100) + aid2
        detaildict['current_playercount'], data = read_byte(data)
        detaildict['max_players'], data = read_byte(data)
        detaildict['current_botcount'], data = read_byte(data)
        ded, data = read_char(data)
        if ded == 'd':
            detaildict['server_type'] = 'Dedicated'
        else:
            detaildict['server_type'] = 'Listen'
        os, data = read_char(data)
        if os == 'w':
            detaildict['server_os'] = 'Windows'
        else:
            detaildict['server_os'] = 'Linux'
        pworded, data = read_byte(data)
        detaildict['passworded'] = bool(int(pworded))
        secured, data = read_byte(data)
        detaildict['secure'] = bool(int(secured))
        detaildict['exe_version'], data = read_string(data)

        return detaildict

    def _details_hl1(self, data):
        detaildict = {}
        detaildict['hl_version'] = 1
        detaildict['game_ip'], data = read_string(data)
        detaildict['server_name'], data = read_string(data)
        detaildict['current_map'], data = read_string(data)
        detaildict['game_directory'], data = read_string(data)
        detaildict['game_description'], data = read_string(data)
        detaildict['current_playercount'], data = read_byte(data)
        detaildict['max_players'], data = read_byte(data)
        detaildict['protocol_version'], data = read_byte(data)
        ded, data = read_char(data)
        if ded == 'd':
            detaildict['server_type'] = 'Dedicated'
        else:
            detaildict['server_type'] = 'Listen'
        os, data = read_char(data)
        if os == 'w':
            detaildict['server_os'] = 'Windows'
        else:
            detaildict['server_os'] = 'Linux'
        pworded, data = read_byte(data)
        detaildict['passworded'] = bool(int(pworded))
        detaildict['ismod'], data = read_byte(data)
        if detaildict['ismod'] == 1:
            detaildict['mod_url_info'], data = read_string(data)
            detaildict['mod_url_dl'], data = read_string(data)
            detaildict['mod_unused'], data = read_string(data)
            detaildict['mod_version'], data = read_int(data)
            detaildict['mod_size'], data = read_int(data)
            mod_svonly, data = read_byte(data)
            detaildict['mod_svonly'] = bool(int(mod_svonly))
            mod_cldll, data = read_byte(data)
            detaildict['mod_cldll'] = bool(int(mod_cldll))
        secured, data = read_byte(data)
        detaildict['secure'] = bool(int(secured))
        detaildict['current_botcount'], data = read_byte(data)

        return detaildict

    def players(self):
        if self.challenge == -1:
            self.getchallenge()
        raw_players = self._any_response(PLAYERS + hldspack_int(self.challenge))
        if raw_players[0] != PLAYERS_RESP: raise SRCDS_Error, 'Player Query Error'
        data = raw_players[1:]
        playerlist = []
        playercount, data = read_byte(data)
        playercount = int(playercount)
        while len(data) != 0:
            currentplayer = {}
            cn, data = read_byte(data)
            currentplayer['index'] = int(cn)
            currentplayer['name'], data = read_string(data)
            currentplayer['frags'], data = read_int(data)
            currentplayer['time_on'], data = read_float(data)
            playerlist.append(currentplayer)
        return playerlist

    def rules(self):
        if self.challenge == -1:
            self.getchallenge()
        raw_rules = self._any_response(RULES + hldspack_int(self.challenge))
        if raw_rules[0] != RULES_RESP: raise SRCDS_Error, 'Rules Query Error'
        data = raw_rules[1:]
        rulescount, data = read_byte(data)
        rulescount = int(rulescount)
        nada, data = read_byte(data)    #placeholder to move up one byte
        ruleslist = string.split(str(data), '\x00')
        ruleslist.pop()
        rulesdict =  {}
        for everyother in ruleslist[::2]:
            rulesdict[everyother] = ruleslist[ruleslist.index(everyother) + 1]
        return rulesdict

    def disconnect(self):
        self.udpsock.close()

##################################################
# HLDS class (for backwards compatibility with HLDS.py)
class HLDS(SRCDS):
    def close(self):
        self.disconnect()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = OptionParser(usage="SRCDS.py -a ADDR -p RCONPASS [command]")
    parser.add_option("-p",dest="rcon",default="",help="Specifies the rcon password")
    parser.add_option("-a",dest="addr",default="",help="Specifies the address of the server to connect to")
    (options,args) = parser.parse_args()

    if not options.addr:
        os.system(sys.argv[0] + " -h")
        sys.exit(1)

    print("Connecting to %s with rcon password of %s" % (options.addr,options.rcon))
    s = SRCDS(options.addr,rconpass=options.rcon)

    if not args:
        # run testing procedures
        print("*"*66)
        print("Testing module...")
        print("*"*66)

        sinfo,d = s.status()
        for u in d:
            print ("userid %d, name = %s" % (u,d[u]['name']))

        print("Server name    : " + sinfo['name'])
        print("IP             : %s" % sinfo['ip'])
        print("Port           : %s" % sinfo['port'])
        print("FPS            : %s" % sinfo['fps'])
        print("CPU Usage      : %s" % sinfo['cpu_usage'])
        print("Server version : %s" % sinfo['version'])
        print("Players present: %d" % sinfo['players'])
        print("Number of slots: %d" % sinfo['slots'])
        print("Map            : " + sinfo['map'])
        print("Passworded     : " + str(sinfo['passworded']))
        print("Secure         : " + str(sinfo['secure']))
        print("sv_gravity     : " + s.cvar("sv_gravity"))
    else:
        # run the rcon command that the user specified
        print s.rcon_command(' '.join(args))
```

Would like to know how would be possible to do it.

Comment: Take a look at the if statement at the bottom of the file you posted. parser.add_option() does what you're looking for, but you'll need to add the logic to handle the port as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can add an option the exact same way the other options are added. Down near the bottom, where you see these lines:

```
parser.add_option("-p",dest="rcon",default="",help="Specifies the rcon password")
parser.add_option("-a",dest="addr",default="",help="Specifies the address of the server to connect to")
```

… add another one, something like this:

```
parser.add_option("-x",dest="port",default="",help="Specifies the port of the server to connect to")
```

Now, you need to *use* that. Look a few lines down to see how `addr` is used:

```
print("Connecting to %s with rcon password of %s" % (options.addr,options.rcon))
s = SRCDS(options.addr,rconpass=options.rcon)
```

Then look at the `SRCDS` constructor. It's got a nice docstring that shows how to use it:

```
Initialization: OBJ = SRCDS(host, [port=27015], [rconpass=''], [timeout=2.0])
```

So, it's an extra parameter, which you can pass by keyword.

The only remaining problem is that command-line arguments are strings, but the function needs a number. So, call `int` on it.

```
if options.port:
    s = SRCDS(options.addr, port=int(options.port), rconpass=options.rcon)
else:
    s = SRCDS(options.addr, rconpass=options.rcon)
```

Comment: int! all this time I had been getting type error. Thank you.

Comment: @GaNi: Ah, you were passing the string `"27015"` to the constructor? If you're coming from a language that automatically converts things between strings and numbers (like Tcl—or like PHP and JavaScript sometimes but not other times), you need to get used to this difference. Whenever you see a `TypeError`, remember that this could be the cause.